# Why isn't a DOM node rendered by React considered a node by React.PropTypes.node validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, react-dom

Let's say I have two components:

An overlay trigger:

```
import {openOverlay} from './overlay-actions'

class OverlayTrigger extends Component {
    handleMouseOver(event) {
        // updates global store
        openOverlay({
            triggerNode: this.refs.container
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref="container" onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver.bind(this)}></div>;
    }
}

// ...map actions to dispatch here

export default OverlayTrigger;
```

And the overlay container component which gets its props from a parent component that watches a global store for the active overlay definition, which has a triggerNode prop.

```
class OverlayContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}

OverlayContainer.propTypes = {
    triggerNode: PropTypes.node
}

export default OverlayContainer;
```

The result here is that `triggerNode` as passed to OverlayContainer is a valid DOM node, but fails the validation by ReactPropTypes' `isNode` validator. Why? And how can this be resolved?

Comment: The documentation says about `node`: *"Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types."*. A DOM node is neither a number, nor a string, nor a (React) element. But I  somehow that you are actually passing a DOM node. What exactly are you passing? Please show your code.

Comment: If someone answered your question correctly, click the empty checkmark next to the answer to mark it correct. Otherwise, update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
triggerNode: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)
```

to verify DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks. I was also looking for the "why", so this is only a partial answer. The "why", I have found, is that react components such as `<MyComponent>` are identified as React nodes while native DOM elements such as '<div>' are identified as DOM elements.